# Combine Two Select Statements Using UNION

Tags: mysql, sql

I am learning some SQL statements, I cannot see why my code cannot execute from my database:

```
(SELECT Time FROM mytable)
UNION
(SELECT Travel FROM mytable);
```

The above statement is forbidden.

Comment: did you select database ? before run this query ?

Comment: Yes, the statements work when selected individually

Comment: try changing `UNION` to `UNION ALL`

Comment: Yep, tried that as well before, same error returned:

Error in Processing Request
Error code: 403
Error text: Forbidden

Comment: are time and travel the same type?

Comment: `Time` and `Travel` are in two different tables right? Also try removing the parenthesis.

Comment: have you try `SELECT * from table UNION SELECT * from table` ? it is working then your column type might be problem or column `collation` ?

Comment: well, obviously time travel is forbidden

Comment: I've noticed something strange, after executing the command, I no longer have permission access on myphpadmin unless I log out and log in again, all other select quires run fine but whenever I use UNION I loose permissions again.. This not only happens with Time/Travel but all column names (strings, ints ect), I don't understand why I have full permissions to insert, update, delete and run select statements but not with UNION

Comment: Also, I have to clear browser history before being able to log back in again - Bug?

Comment: Couple of things I've noticed: Time is a keyword in MySql It *should* be escaped with backticks if you insist on using it as a column name. e.g. SELECT `Time` FROM mytable. The error you're seeing is from MyPHPAdmin and isn't super-helpful. Can you get any more info out of the tool, or, even better, access the db using the mysql command-line app?

Answer (score 1):

It does not look like columns called `Time` and `Travel` would be of the same datatype... When you `UNION` two select statements, you are effectively putting the two values in the same column. SQL does not know what type to make the column. Likely, it sees the `Time` values, makes the column a `DATETIME` column, an then you start trying to cram `Travel` `VARCHAR` strings into it.

Try casting both as the same type, like this:

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(Time, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') Time
FROM myTable

UNION

SELECT
  Travel
FROM myTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are different types I'm guessing you want this:

```
SELECT Time as TimeValue, null as TravelValue FROM mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT null as TimeValue, Travel as TravelValue FROM mytable;
```

or this

```
SELECT Time, Travel FROM mytable;
```

Comment: Whenever I use the UNION I get: (Error in Processing Request, Error code: 403, Error text: Forbidden) but if I remove the keyword "UNION" I get a normal SQL error query (and yes the query should give an error because I have two 'select' statements without 'union') - I have tried all answers provided and I can conclude that MY MySQL does not want UNION at all, it doesn't even return a normal SQL error, remove it then I get a normal SQL error, everything else works fine until I add UNION to any statement.